# How to make a value_of_things function f#

Tags: f#, f#-interactive, f#-3.0

Hey guys let's say I have a function that gets that day's rate of how much something costs, by the pound, and multiplies it by how many pounds a customer wants. i.e

```
let convert_func (crab_rate, lobster_rate);

//and then on a certain day it is
 let (crab_rate, lobster_rate) = convert_fun(3.4, 6.8); // $3.8 a pound for crab, $6.8 a pound for lobster.
// 10 being how many pounds i want.
crab_rate10 ;
```

Then my out put would be whatever 38 since ($3.8 * 10lbs) = $38
I tried doing if statements so that when the user just wants to find out the total cost of one thing and not both. But I keep getting errors. I can't figure out how to store the rate values in the parameters and then calling the function.
This is what i tried

```
let crab_rate (pound, rate) = (float pound) * rate;
let lobster_rate (pound, rate) = (float pound) * rate;

let convert_func (crab_rate, lobster_rate)= function (first,second ) ->
 if crab_rate then (float pound) * rate;
 elif lobster_rate (float pound) * rate;


 let (crab_rate, lobster_rate) = convert_fun(3.4, 6.8); // $3.8 a pound for crab, $6.8 a pound for lobster.
// 10 being how many pounds i want.
crab_rate10 ;
```

Comment: Post your attempted code and the errors.

Comment: Maybe, you want something like: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Nv7bXi

Comment: @Nick Morales, Your issue has been resolved?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should start by making a general function for converting a cost/weight and a weight into a cost.  In F#, you can even use units of measure to help you:

```
[<Measure>] type USD // Unit of measure: US Dollars
[<Measure>] type lb // Unit of measure: lbs

let priceForWeight rate (weight : float<lb>) : float<USD> =
    rate * weight
```

The nice thing about functional languages with curried arguments is that we can easily use partial function application.  That means when we have a function that has two arguments, we can choose to supply just one argument and get back a new function from that one remaining argument to the result.

We can therefore define a further pair of functions that use this `priceForWeight` function.

```
let crabPriceForWeight weight = priceForWeight 3.8<USD/lb> weight
let lobsterPriceForWeight weight = priceForWeight 6.8<USD/lb> weight
```

Notice that we've used our original function to define two new functions with fixed rates.

We can then evaluate it like this:

```
let crabPrice10 = crabPriceForWeight 10.0<lb> // result 38.0<USD>
```

Of course, you can also define a function that returns both prices together as a tuple for a supplied weight:

```
let crabAndLobsterPriceForWeight weight = 
    crabPriceForWeight weight, lobsterPriceForWeight weight
```